# .htaccess redirect "old-domain" (with subfolders) to "new-domain" (keep subfolders)

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, redirect

I have a hosting packet with domain: **olddomain.com**.
In cpanel "**olddomain.com**" is the main domain.

In cpanel i added another domain "**newdomain.eu**", by used "Aliases" process.

i am looking for a solution to redirect the **olddomain.com** to **newdomain.eu**
but not only the main domain but, and the subdirectories.

**olddomain.com/something** to **newdomain.eu/something** or **olddomain.com/something2** to **newdomain.eu/something2**

i tried this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newdomain.eu/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But olny the **olddomain.com** redirect to **newdomain.eu** when i try a domain with subfolder stay as is:

**olddomain.com/something** stay **olddomain.com/something**

any idea?

Comment: It might be that your `subfolder/.htaccess` is conflicting with your main htaccess. Try removing your htaccess from the subfolder.

Comment: thnx i will checkit